# D3 force layout fix root node at the center

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

I managed to draw some basic d3 force layout graph, but struggling how to fix root node at the center.

My data is rather simple; one root node with one-level children. Only one level.
Another particular thing about my graph is that the link distance varies based on some parameter.

I want root node to be at the center of the graph.

Setting its property 'fixed':true doesn't work.
Any idea to place root node at the center?

Comment: Example [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1080941). Look inside force.on at the first two lines.

Comment: I just followed the example again, carefully this time and it works.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
force.on("tick", function() {
    nodes[0].x = w / 2;
    nodes[0].y = h / 2;
```

That should do it.

Comment: Is it possible to alter the behaviour in a way that the node is initially centered but the user can still move it?

Comment: In d3 4.0 this doesn't fix nodes but just sets the coordinates. To fix the node use "fx" and "fy"