# D3.js - how can I position a force chart upwards and to the left of a page?

Tags: d3.js, charts, force-layout

I have a force network graph (in a Drupal site) which does what I want it to (thanks to many members of stackoverflow) but it ends up about 400px from the top and left margins of the content area.(see http://trsg.tcan.ca/stronger-together-network)

Which parameters control this?

Comment: See if [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21843206/d3-force-layout-fix-root-node-at-the-center) helps. This positions the root node. You can also google for other examples.

Comment: Sadly, this didn't work for me. There is a tick function which I modified following your example but what happened was that it was totally scrunched up in a line. Here it is: function tick() {
//    nodes[0].x = width / 2; 
//    nodes[0].y = height / 2;
  link
      .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });
  node
      .attr("transform", function(d) { 
           return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; 
      });
};

Comment: As another possibility besides Pablo's, and one I was playing with...you can also change the size of the `d3.layout.force` per se, not the overall graph...like this: `var force = d3.layout.force().size([width/2, height/2])` and you would leave the other properties as is. You can try that as well. Actually, I think this is what Pablo meant by a smaller network chart, noting again that this would be the size of the force layout, not the overall svg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assigning the layout to Body instead of a DIV solved the problem. (In most other scripts I had to use a DIV and using Body caused problems.)

Answer (score 1):

The force layout is designed to distribute items in the available space. When you create a force layout, you set the size of the available area, and the nodes are attracted to the center of the area.

You can either set a smaller area for the network chart or lower the attraction between the nodes and the center, by setting the charge attribute of the force to a greater value. The default value is -30, try with -10 or -5.

Comment: I'll look into the suggestions you have both made but I hacked the tick function: `function tick() {
    link
      .attr("x1", function(d) { 
           return d.source.x + xadj; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { 
           return d.source.y + yadj; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { 
           return d.target.x +xadj; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { 
           return d.target.y +yadj; });
    node
      .attr("transform", function(d) { 
           return "translate(" + (d.x + xadj) + "," + (d.y + yadj) + ")"; 
      });
  };` and setting variables xadj and yadj to negative values

Comment: Setting the charge attribute has no effect, nor linkDistance. Perhaps that is the problem. Perhaps there is a problem with the force layout definition.

Comment: I was wrong about force layout having no effect. I was modifying an existing script and did not notice that force layout was defined twice. linkDistance now works correctly but I still have problems positioning the area.

Comment: Try setting the size of the force layout with a smaller width and height. Note that the force layout stores the state in the data objects (the `x` attribute in the nodes), if you use the nodes in a second force layout the attributes will get overwritten. Can you create a fiddle  reproducing the issue?

Comment: I had tried changing the size but after some experimentation I realized that assigning the layout to Body instead of a DIV solved the problem. In most other scripts I had to use a DIV and using Body caused problems.