# D3 radial force layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

I am working on a d3 force layout which requires the nodes to be placed in such a way that there is a central node according to which all the other nodes are radially placed.The nodes are linked to each other like a normal force layout with appropriate source and target.  The central node is dictating the position of all the other nodes, so essentially it is the source of all the nodes. Right now all I have been able to manage to do is to place them in a linear fashion using the linkDistance property with one node as the reference, but I need it in a radial manner. I could have shown an image but apparently my reputation is too low and I am not being allowed to post one.Can someone help me out with this?

Comment: If the data is [hierarchical with a single root node](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Hierarchy-Layout#user-content-children), then place the root node at center, as seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21843206/d3-force-layout-fix-root-node-at-the-center#21843473).

Comment: The data is not hierarchical

Comment: Have you seen [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/vlandham/5087480)? It sounds as if you wouldn't need the force layout if all you want is to arrange nodes in a circle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at this example:

[link to jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VividD/2g5T9/)

[image]

Central (root) node has special treatment that makes it always remain in the center of the graph. On initialization, central node's property `fixed` is set to true, so that d3 force layout simulation doesn't move it. Also, it is placed in the center of rectangle containing layout:

```
root.fixed = true;
root.x = width / 2;
root.y = height / 2;
```

Hope this helps.