# Placing the nodes in the center of screen in d3 force layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js

How can i place the nodes in the center of the force layout in d3.js.
Here i'm getting the JSON data, which is like this

```
"nodes": [{
    "cName": "User",
    "cImage_url": "/final/images/component_icons/user_image.png",
    "x": 49.99999999999999,
    "y": 150,
    "fixed": true
}, {
    "cType": "Oracle WebLogic",
    "cName": "weblogic177:7001",
    "cImage_url": "/final/images/Light/component_icons/APPLICATION_SERVERS.png",
    "x": 167,
    "y": 150,
    "fixed": true,
    "AlarmPopup": "WebLogic_server:weblogic177:7001",
    "cStateImage_url": "/final/images/Light/state20_INTERMEDIATE.png",
    "linktoLayermodel": "/final/monitor/EgDispLayers.jsp?site=egurkha.physical.topology&qctr=0&host=weblogic177:7001&comptype=Oracle WebLogic&comeFrom=topology&To=layerMode&isFromZone=null&iszoneName=&parentZone=null&tab=LayerModel&toDashBoardLayer=true"
}, {
    "cType": "Group",
    "cName": "hari11",
    "cImage_url": "/final/images/component_icons/group.png",
    "x": 283.99999999999994,
    "y": 49.99999999999999,
    "fixed": true,
    "AlarmPopup": "Group:hari11:NULL",
    "cStateImage_url": "/final/images/Light/state20_LOW.png",
    "linktoLayermodel": "/final/monitor/EgDisplayGroups.jsp?ptype=group&showsitesegments=false&group=hari11&serverType=Group&site=egurkha.physical.topology&segmentName=sample&fromHomepage=true"
}..
```

so the nodes always starting from left corner of the screen but i need to start it from center.[image]

so how can i manipulate the existing  x, y in the JSON data?

[image]

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21843206/d3-force-layout-fix-root-node-at-the-center

Comment: its doesn't work because x and y are coming from json data

Comment: I don't see why it shouldn't work -- the data can certainly be modified after being read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly what Lars said.

```
force.on("tick", function() {
    nodes[0].x = w / 2;
    nodes[0].y = h / 2;}
```

this puts the first node in the middle of the screen (nodes[0] means first node) and if you want all the nodes to move to the right do something like this :

```
var movement = 200;

    node.attr("transform", function(d)
    { 
    return "translate(" + movement + "," + 0 + ")"; }); //Here you move the nodes
        ;
```

This basically goes through the nodes and moves every one to the right 200px.
I did the same for the links :

```
link.attr("transform", function(d)
        { 
        return "translate(" + movement + "," + 0 + ")"; }); //Here you move the links
            ;
```

Updated JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/aVhd8/159/

Comment: do you have a JSFiddle i could check ?

Comment: but basically   force.on("tick", function(d, i) {console.log(i)}); Im getting undefined

Comment: force.on("tick", function(d, i) {graph.rootJson.nodes.forEach(function(d, i) {
     graph.rootJson.nodes[i].x = graph.rootJson.nodes[i].x + options.width;
     graph.rootJson.nodes[i].y = graph.rootJson.nodes[i].y + options.width;
    });}) this is working for me but position are not setting properly

Comment: obviously what i gave you doesnt work. stupid me. that would move the nodes more to the right every frame. Ill updated the answer :) Also, the 'i' wasnt getting found as it was using the 'force' to get the data from not the 'nodes' like i have in the updated answer :)

Comment: yes you are right.Its not working out in drag and more to the right

Comment: do you understand how the nodes are being moved now then ? If you do the translate i did in the answer before you call the force.tick() then it should work fine..... i think .....

Comment: yes seems nodes and links are moving some where else. As show in the image

Comment: Ah ok cool, think you need to update the links/edges positions too. So links.attr( ..... Your tick function should handle the new positions of the nodes though. Did you translate the nodes before you call the tick function ?

Comment: NO , im not translate the nodes before

Comment: translate them before otherwise the tick function will update the original position data not the updated

Comment: try put a simplified version of it on JSFiddle then ill be able to find the problem. Its difficult to tell you what to do when I can't see the code :/

Comment: plz chk the link. I think you can do this.:) What i need is to position  nodes to fit in center of the screen. In my json data x and y is there.Also support zoom and drag

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74246/discussion-between-aj-91-and-fekkydev).